# D3.JS how to count number of circles of a certain attribute on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Lets say I have several circles made in D3 and all take this mouseover function...

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    //I get the co attribute of the one being hovered
    var theCompany = d3.select(this).attr("co"); 
    //and then I style all of the circles with that same co attribute       
    d3.selectAll("circle.circle[co='"+theCompany+"']").attr("stroke", "#999"); 
}
```

Is there a way, in this mouseover function, to count the number of circles with that "co" attribute I'm hovering over?

Comment: [selection.size](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#size)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `d3.js` built in method `size` to get the count of selected items.

`var count = d3.selectAll("circle.circle[co='"+theCompany+"']").size()`

In addition (this may come in handy with the previous function) there is a method to check wether the selection is empty or not as well.

`d3.select('<selector'>).empty()` this will return `true/false` based on wether your selection has any results or not.